Implementation of unregister_chrdev_region()
So, I am currently learning how to write kernel modules/device drivers and was looking into the implementation of unregister_chrdev_region:
https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.12/source/fs/char_dev.c#L311
/**
 * unregister_chrdev_region() - unregister a range of device numbers
 * @from: the first in the range of numbers to unregister
 * @count: the number of device numbers to unregister
 *
 * This function will unregister a range of @count device numbers,
 * starting with @from.  The caller should normally be the one who
 * allocated those numbers in the first place...
 */
void unregister_chrdev_region(dev_t from, unsigned count)
{
    dev_t to = from + count;
    dev_t n, next;

    for (n = from; n < to; n = next) {
        next = MKDEV(MAJOR(n)+1, 0);
        if (next > to)
            next = to;
        kfree(__unregister_chrdev_region(MAJOR(n), MINOR(n), next - n));
    }
}

What I don't understand is the check on this line:
https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.12/source/fs/char_dev.c#L318
if (next > to) next = to;

The loop, as I see, already breaks when the loop variable is equal to the upper limit to = from + count. When would we have the case that we run into the conditional if (next > to)? What's the reason of this conditional check?

unregister_chrdev_region unregisters a range of devices, but that unregistration must be handled per major using __unregister_chrdev_region. The loop handles this:

on entry, n is the start of the device range for the current major
next = MKDEV(MAJOR(n)+1, 0); extracts the major number for device n, and uses that to calculate the start of the next major range
if next is greater than to, the current range is entirely contained within the current major, and unregistration needs to stop at to rather than next

In all cases, __unregister_chrdev_region is called to unregister whatever is left in the current major range, and next is set to the start of the next major range or the end of the overall range so that the next iteration of the loop handles the next major range or exits if everything has been handled.
Let’s take an example: if you asked to unregister 1024 devices starting at major 1, minor 512:

on entry to the function, from is 1536, count is 1024
to is calculated to be 2560
on entry to the loop, n is 1536
next is calculated to be 2048 (major 2)
2048 is less than 2560, so __unregister_chrdev_region is called to unregister 512 devices starting at 1536
on the next iteration of the loop, n is 2048
next is calculated to be 3072 (major 3)
3072 is greater than 2560, so next is set to to, and __unregister_chrdev_region is called to unregister 512 devices starting at 2048
on the next iteration of the loop, n is 2560 and the loop ends


Many thx for the detailed explanation. Now I have a better understanding of this function that it unregisters a range of devices, where the range can span over multiple majors.

You're misinterpreting what the loop does! The loop is not
//                        vvv
for(int n = from; n < to; n++) {
  /* Do something treating n as a constant each iteration */
}

which runs exactly to - from == count times.
It is, instead,
//                        vvvvvvvv
for(int n = from; n < to; n = next) {
   next = something_that_might_or_might_not_change_each_iteration();
}

in this case,
next=MKDEV(MAJOR(n)+1, 0);

If you look up the definition of MKDEV and MAJOR, you'll see that this expands to
next =  ((n >> 20) + 1) << 20 | 0; 

which amounts to "round up to the next multiple of 220 (even if n is already a multiple)".
So, it's quite likely that already in the first iteration your next would be larger than to!

Ahhh, right, the device ID is composed of having the upper 12 bits as the major. Thx for the explanation.

oh that was the main source of confusion? I thought it was the for loop structure! In that case, Stephen's answer is actually a lot more detailed than mine.

Not the structure itself but I was counting next by incrementing with just +1 for some reason, although there was ths MACRO for setting it :)

yeah that's what I meant with structure :)
